# latest version of mapreduce libs on maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, mapreduce

i created a simple java project in eclipse using default maven archtype. 
i then added junit and hadoop-core dependencies. 
the latest version of hadoop-core available on maven is -

```
group id: org.apache.hadoop
artifact id: hadoop-core
version: 1.2.1
```

looks like this was released in Jul 2013. info - http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core

is this the latest version of mapreduce out there? if not, whats the best way to get the latest version and incoporate it in my project (example: another maven dependency, direct download, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like they have now uploaded the latest version of hadoop and mapreduce libs under a new name.

```
group id: org.apache.hadoop
artifact id: hadoop-client
version: 2.7.0
```

removing hadoop-core and adding this hadoop-client means now i have latest mapreduce libs (upto version 2.7.0).

PS: If you are building a jar for Cloudera or AWS-EMR, you can find the older versions of mapreduce libs under hadoop-client too.

Answer (score 1):

For searching for artifacts i would recomment to use the Search Engine of Maven Central:

```
http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Corg.apache.hadoop
```

Comment: Thanks! I used that to locate the latest libs.